# Order of items in set has been changed, Set, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, set

Im creating 2 sets which are containing `String` like following

```
 let set1 : Set<String>   =   (["07:00", "QShift", "PRN"])
 let set2 : Set<String>   =   (["07:15", "QShift", "PRN"])
```

At first, I am thinking the order of strings in each set will be exactly as same as their orders when being added. However I was wrong about the one of `set1`, the console gives me this

```
Printing description of set1:
▿ 3 elements
  - [0] : "QShift"
  - [1] : "PRN"
  - [2] : "07:00" { ... }

Printing description of set2:
▿ 3 elements
  - [0] : "07:15"
  - [1] : "QShift"
  - [2] : "PRN" { ... }
```

Does anyone know why the order of strings in `set1` has been changed to `QShift, PRN, 07:00`?

Comment: A set is, by definition, an unordered collection.

Comment: BTW, this is the second question I've seen on this exact topic, and I'd like to understand what is leading to the confusion so we can help others better. @tonytran, why did you explicitly request a Set here when you clearly want an Array? You had to go to extra trouble and extra typing to request a Set, and most tutorials (correctly) teach Arrays. What led you to choose Set?

Comment: @RobNapier: I chose the set because I did not want any duplications in the set.If I used the array, I could certainly avoid duplication but I had to do extra work in oder to add item in the list.

Comment: OK, the tool designed for that is `NSOrderedSet`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `Set` is an unordered data structure.

[Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) reference:

> A set stores distinct values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. You can use a set instead of an array when the order of items is not important, or when you need to ensure that an item only appears once.

You should take a look at [NSOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/) class reference, for more APIs:

> NSOrderedSet and its subclass, NSMutableOrderedSet, declare the programmatic interfaces to an ordered collection of objects.

Comment: You should look at arrays for that. An NSOrderedSet was mostly added for Core Data (didn't exist till then) and should not be your first choice. Please refer to http://nshipster.com/nsorderedset/

Comment: Agreed. NSOrderedSet is a troubled type that doesn't even work very well for Core Data (unfortunately). An Array or Dictionary are almost always the correct collection type.

Comment: But sometimes you need both ordering and quick containment checks -- neither Array not Dictionary offer that. Swift really needs OrderedSet (and OrderedDictionary) types.

Answer (score 0):

[OrderedSet On Github.](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Ordered%20Set)

that should work for your need.